# How to use "IWebHostEnvironment" inside static class in ASP Core

Tags: c#, class, .net-core, dependency-injection, static-classes

Is there a way to use "IWebHostEnvironment" inside static class in ASP Core?

**My class :**

```
public class MainHelper
{
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

    public MainHelper(IWebHostEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
        _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
    }    

    public static void SaveFile(IFormFile file)
    {
            var path = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "uploads");
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

            using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(Path.Combine(path, file.FileName)))
            {
                file.CopyTo(fileStream);
            }
    }
}
```

I have error in line:

```
var path = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "uploads");
```

**Error:** c# session an object reference is required for the non-static field method or property 'MainHelper._hostingEnvironment'

Please Advise

Comment: You can't use non-static class members at static methods, because you need initialize them first. Why you marked `SaveFile` as static? Maybe remove `static` keyword at `SaveFile` is your solution?

Comment: I know when I remove "static" it will give no errors, could you provide an example how to use it then? 
And I need to use it like MainHelper.SaveFile(file) , if you could find a way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like that can help you:

```cs
public static class MainHelper
{
    private static IWebHostEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

    public static bool IsInitialized { get; private set; }

    public static void Initialize(IWebHostEnvironment hostEnvironment)
    {
        if(IsInitialized)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Object already initialized");
        
        _hostingEnvironment = hostEnvironment;
        IsInitialized = true;
    }

    public static void SaveFile(IFormFile file)
    {
        if(!IsInitialized)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Object is not initialized");

        var path = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "uploads");
        if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

        using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(Path.Combine(path, file.FileName)))
        {
            file.CopyTo(fileStream);
        }
    }
}
```

It this sample you should call `MainHelper.Initialize` with your `IWebHostEnvironment` instance at your `Startup.cs`, etc. instead calling constructor. In this sample you can initialize `MainHelper` just once. (Not tested)

Comment: Thanks for your perfect solution, I found that if I add "IWebHostEnvironment"  to parameters, it did not give any errors : "public static void SaveFile(IWebHostEnvironment _hostingEnvironment, IFormFile file)", is that right?

Comment: @Neven Yes, if you have access to `IWebHostEnvironment` at any place where you call `SaveFile`. My approach allows you pass `IWebHostEnvironment` once. Because `IWebHostEnvironment` is unique for application, you don't need to pass it every time in `SaveFile`.

Answer (score 8):

As the accepted answer was one.
But in case anyone refers using without intialization in static class:

```
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

    public class Common{
          public static IWebHostEnvironment WebEnv()
            {
                var _accessor = new HttpContextAccessor();
                return _accessor.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IWebHostEnvironment>();
            }
        }
```

Usage:

```
var path = Common.WebEnv().WebRootPath;
```

Answer (score 2):

There is already an accepted answer but one similar solution to @sambath999 answers is as follows:

```
public static class MainHelper
{
    public static HttpContext _httpContext => new HttpContextAccessor().HttpContext;
    public static IWebHostEnvironment _webHostEnvironment => (IWebHostEnvironment)_httpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(IWebHostEnvironment));
}
```

Register **HttpcontextAccessor** in **Program.cs**

```
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

Now you can use _webHostEnvironment in your static class:

```
var path = MainHelper._webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath;
```

I hope this would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
   var environment = app.ApplicationServices
                .CreateScope()
                .ServiceProvider
                .GetRequiredService<IWebHostEnvironment>();
```