# How do I get a reference to IWebHostEnvironment inside a library project? (Also inside static class :()

Tags: .net, .net-5, library-project, server.mappath

I need to use Server.MapPath. Since library projects does not have Startup.cs i cannot apply the normal way.

Comment: .NET 5 is .NET *Core* 5. The question is unclear, but if you google for `Server.MapPath ASP.NET Core` you'll find a lot of answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the equivalent of Server.MapPath in ASP.NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49398965/what-is-the-equivalent-of-server-mappath-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: So your real question should be: _How do I get a reference to IWebHostEnvironment inside a library project? (and inside a static class)_

Comment: Yes, I will submit as you said

Comment: This might be helpful and resolve your puzzle. [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64482399/how-to-use-iwebhostenvironment-inside-static-class-in-asp-core). Here a static class which have property as `IWebHostEnvironment`. You can call initialize from startup.cs and then use it across your application.

Comment: [Link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64482399/how-to-use-iwebhostenvironment-inside-static-class-in-asp-core
This is the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, register HttpcontextAccessor service in Startup.cs of the project which uses the Library project,

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

then in the class,

```
private static HttpContext _httpContext => new HttpContextAccessor().HttpContext;
private static IWebHostEnvironment _env => (IWebHostEnvironment)_httpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(IWebHostEnvironment));
```

now you can access it in a static class and a static method.

This did the trick for me. If anyone needs.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution in **.NET 6.0** is as follows:

```
public static class MainHelper
{
    public static IWebHostEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;
    public static bool IsInitialized { get; private set; }
    public static void Initialize(IWebHostEnvironment hostEnvironment)
    {
        if (IsInitialized)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Object already initialized");

        _hostingEnvironment = hostEnvironment;
        IsInitialized = true;
    }
}
```

Register HttpcontextAccessor and send parameters to Initialize in **Program.cs**

```
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
MainHelper.Initialize(builder.Environment);
```

Now you can use **_hostingEnvironment** in any where in your project like following:

```
var path = MainHelper._hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath;
```

or

```
var path = MainHelper._hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
```